# How can I re-use the navigation bar in multiple pages (Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I will keep this short. Simply, I got a navigation bar that I have in <index.html>. How can I reuse that navigation bar on a different page than index?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The functionality you are looking for is referred to as templating. Templating allows you to create blocks of HTML that can be included and re-used various places throughout a web page/site.

For static content (plain HTML pages), [Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/), [Hugo](https://gohugo.io/), and [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/) are all good choices with lots of documentation and strong community support.

Answer (score -1):

Quite simple
Just copy the code of that navigation bar from index.html
And paste it on ur other page...